# select routes based on roles

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I'm trying to create role-based routes, however I can't figure it out how to display specific pages that relies on which role user has.
Example:

```
<Route exact path="/users">
          {(localStorage.getItem("role") === "ROLE_ADMIN" && (
            <Appbar/>) && (
            <Users/>))}
        </Route>
```

So let's say when user with ROLE_ADMIN directs to /users path, it should display  and  components. But I want to direct him to the other component if he doesn't have that role. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's common to create a custom route component to handle checking the role. Pass the `role` as a prop to the custom route and check against what is stored in localStorage and conditionally return a `Route` or `Redirect` component.

Example:

```
const RoleRoute = ({ role, ...props }) => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("role")) === role
    ? <Route {...props} />
    : <Redirect to="/" />;
};
```

Usage:

```
<RoleRoute exact path="/users" role="ROLE_ADMIN">
  <Appbar/>
  <Users/>
</Route>
```

This is assuming you are using `react-router-dom@5` since that appears to be the route syntax/props of your code example. If you are using `react-router-dom@6` the logic changes a bit.

```
const RoleWrapper = ({ role }) => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("role")) === role
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

Usage:

```
<Route element={<RoleWrapper role="ROLE_ADMIN" />}>
  <Route
    path="/users"
    element={(
      <>
        <Appbar/>
        <Users/>
      </>
    )}
  />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ternary condition as follow:

```
    {
     localStorage.getItem("role") === "ROLE_ADMIN" ? <Appbar /> && <Users /> : 
      <Redirect to="/" />;
     }
```

Comment: FYI `<Appbar /> && <Users />` will render ***only*** `<Users />`.

Comment: No problem, you can put these two components in another single component and then use that new component here.